# How do I trace the stack to remove an error in MathCAD?

Tags: debugging, stack-trace, mathcad

Making some calculations with MathCAD I got an error such as:

> Unknown error: A call target threw an exception.

Is there some stack trace which I could investigate to comprehend the situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is Debug mode, Trace window and two functions for debuging: pause and trace for worksheet programm functions.

Your error seems like error in user's function (by UserEFI). In this case, there is a way to return an error with code and message instead of exception. See Mathcad UserEFI Guide.